# Changing elements in div based on another div click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a "list" with three items. Each list by default, shows an **image** and **text**.

When one of these div's is clicked, I want its content to be shown in another div (along with more information).

- The first `clickable-li` content will always be displayed in the secondary div. By content, I am referring to 1. It's image 2. It's header (`h3`) and 3. It's textm which for now is "this is sample text for icon 1".
- From there, any other click any `clickable-li`, it will show its information accordingly.

**Current approach:**

```js
$('#icon-1').click(function() {
  $('image_col-2-wrapper h3').html('icon 1');
  $('image_col-2-wrapper p').html('this is sample text for icon 1');
});

$('#icon-2').click(function() {
  $('image_col-2-wrapper h3').html('icon 2');
  $('image_col-2-wrapper p').html('this is sample text for icon 2');
});

$('#icon-3').click(function() {
  $('image_col-2-wrapper h3').html('icon 3');
  $('image_col-2-wrapper p').html('this is sample text for icon 3');
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 50px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.text_col-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
}

.text_col-1 .clickable-li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image_col-2 {
  background-color: #5fc8c5;
  width: 650px;
}

.image_col-2-wrapper {
  padding: 40px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="container">

  <!-- LEFT -->

  <div class="text_col-1">

    <!-- ICON 1 -->
    <div class="clickable-li" id="icon-1">
      <img id="image" src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/1-circle.png"><br>
      <span>Icon 1</span>
    </div>

    <!-- ICON 2 -->
    <div class="clickable-li" id="icon-2">
      <img id="image" src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/2-circle.png"><br>
      <span>Icon 2</span>
    </div>

    <!-- ICON 3 -->
    <div class="clickable-li" id="icon-3">
      <img id="image" src="http://chittagongit.com/images/3-icon/3-icon-7.jpg">
      <br>
      <span>Icon 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- RIGHT -->

  <div class="image_col-2">
    <div class="image_col-2-wrapper">
      <img src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/1-circle.png">
      <h3>Icon 1</h3>
      <p>this will be the text that appears on li click</p>
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <!---->

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ssamuel said, your issue was the missing `.` in the class name.

⋅
⋅
⋅

Anyway…

You could enhance your code to have only one JavaScript function. And keep all the content in the HTML.

**New snippet** *(using an hidden `div` element as your `html` container)*

```js
$('.clickable-li').click(function(title, text) {
  $('.image_col-2-wrapper h3').html($(this).attr("mytitle"));
  $('.image_col-2-wrapper p').html($(this).find(".mytext").html());
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 50px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.text_col-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
}

.text_col-1 .clickable-li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image_col-2 {
  background-color: #5fc8c5;
  width: 650px;
}

.image_col-2-wrapper {
  padding: 40px;
  height: 100%;
}

.mytext {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <!-- LEFT -->
  <div class="text_col-1">

    <!-- ICON 1 -->
    <div class="clickable-li" id="icon-1" mytitle="Icon 1">
      <img id="image" src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/1-circle.png"><br>
      <span>Icon 1</span>
      <div class="mytext">
        <p>this is sample text for icon 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ICON 2 -->
    <div class="clickable-li" id="icon-2" mytitle="Icon 2">
      <img id="image" src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/2-circle.png"><br>
      <span>Icon 2</span>
      <div class="mytext">
        <p>this is sample text for icon 2</p>
        <h4>But this one also has a header</h4>
        <p>and more text!</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ICON 3 -->
    <div class="clickable-li" id="icon-3" mytitle="Icon 3">
      <img id="image" src="http://chittagongit.com/images/3-icon/3-icon-7.jpg">
      <br>
      <span>Icon 3</span>
      <div class="mytext">this is sample text for icon 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- RIGHT -->
  <div class="image_col-2">
    <div class="image_col-2-wrapper">
      <img src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/1-circle.png">
      <h3>Icon 1</h3>
      <p>this will be the text that appears on li click</p>
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

⋅
⋅
⋅

**Old snippet** *(using custom attributes)*

```js
$('.clickable-li').click(function(title, text) {
  $('.image_col-2-wrapper h3').html($(this).attr("mytitle"));
  $('.image_col-2-wrapper p').html($(this).attr("mytext"));
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 50px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.text_col-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
}

.text_col-1 .clickable-li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image_col-2 {
  background-color: #5fc8c5;
  width: 650px;
}

.image_col-2-wrapper {
  padding: 40px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <!-- LEFT -->
  <div class="text_col-1">

    <!-- ICON 1 -->
    <div class="clickable-li" id="icon-1" mytitle="Icon 1" mytext="this is sample text for icon 1">
      <img id="image" src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/1-circle.png"><br>
      <span>Icon 1</span>
    </div>

    <!-- ICON 2 -->
    <div class="clickable-li" id="icon-2" mytitle="Icon 2" mytext="this is sample text for icon 2">
      <img id="image" src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/2-circle.png"><br>
      <span>Icon 2</span>
    </div>

    <!-- ICON 3 -->
    <div class="clickable-li" id="icon-3" mytitle="Icon 3" mytext="this is sample text for icon 3">
      <img id="image" src="http://chittagongit.com/images/3-icon/3-icon-7.jpg">
      <br>
      <span>Icon 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- RIGHT -->
  <div class="image_col-2">
    <div class="image_col-2-wrapper">
      <img src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/1-circle.png">
      <h3>Icon 1</h3>
      <p>this will be the text that appears on li click</p>
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Takit, this approach looks sustainable. Followup question, lets say one of my divs has more text? I.e. this is what I want one of my `mytext` attributes to look like `mytext= "this is sample text for icon 2<br><h4>But this one also has a header</h4>and more text!"`. How would I go about doing something like this?

Comment: @Freddy Thank you for your comment, I usually try to do sustainable things. :) It will works if you put all the html string you said in the attribute. But I'm going to propose you an alternative solution as well.

Comment: @Freddy Here is the new snippet !

Answer (score 1):

You have to use '.' dot with the class name as `$('.classname').click()`...that was the only issue

```js
$('#icon-1').click(function() {
  $('.image_col-2-wrapper h3').html('icon 1');
  $('.image_col-2-wrapper p').html('this is sample text for icon 1');
});

$('#icon-2').click(function() {
  $('.image_col-2-wrapper h3').html('icon 2');
  $('.image_col-2-wrapper p').html('this is sample text for icon 2');
});

$('#icon-3').click(function() {
  $('.image_col-2-wrapper h3').html('icon 3');
  $('.image_col-2-wrapper p').html('this is sample text for icon 3');
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 50px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.text_col-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
}

.text_col-1 .clickable-li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image_col-2 {
  background-color: #5fc8c5;
  width: 650px;
}

.image_col-2-wrapper {
  padding: 40px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="container">

  <!-- LEFT -->

  <div class="text_col-1">

    <!-- ICON 1 -->
    <div class="clickable-li" id="icon-1">
      <img id="image" src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/1-circle.png"><br>
      <span>Icon 1</span>
    </div>

    <!-- ICON 2 -->
    <div class="clickable-li" id="icon-2">
      <img id="image" src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/2-circle.png"><br>
      <span>Icon 2</span>
    </div>

    <!-- ICON 3 -->
    <div class="clickable-li" id="icon-3">
      <img id="image" src="http://chittagongit.com/images/3-icon/3-icon-7.jpg">
      <br>
      <span>Icon 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- RIGHT -->

  <div class="image_col-2">
    <div class="image_col-2-wrapper">
      <img src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/1-circle.png">
      <h3>Icon 1</h3>
      <p>this will be the text that appears on li click</p>
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <!---->

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a separate click handle. Just one click with a wildcard does that. Use `split` on id to get the desired value and append that on your message. Use `.` for class and `#` for id.

```js
$('[id*="icon"]').click(function(i, ele) {
  var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
  $('.image_col-2-wrapper h3').html('icon ' + id);
  $('.image_col-2-wrapper p').html('this is sample text for icon ' + id);
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 50px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.text_col-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
}

.text_col-1 .clickable-li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image_col-2 {
  background-color: #5fc8c5;
  width: 650px;
}

.image_col-2-wrapper {
  padding: 40px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <!-- LEFT -->

  <div class="text_col-1">

    <!-- ICON 1 -->
    <div class="clickable-li" id="icon-1">
      <img id="image" src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/1-circle.png"><br>
      <span>Icon 1</span>
    </div>

    <!-- ICON 2 -->
    <div class="clickable-li" id="icon-2">
      <img id="image" src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/2-circle.png"><br>
      <span>Icon 2</span>
    </div>

    <!-- ICON 3 -->
    <div class="clickable-li" id="icon-3">
      <img id="image" src="http://chittagongit.com/images/3-icon/3-icon-7.jpg">
      <br>
      <span>Icon 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- RIGHT -->

  <div class="image_col-2">
    <div class="image_col-2-wrapper">
      <img src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/1-circle.png">
      <h3>Icon 1</h3>
      <p>this will be the text that appears on li click</p>
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <!---->

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.clickable-li').click(function(i, elem) {
  var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
   $('.image_col-2-wrapper h3').html('icon ' + id);
  $('.image_col-2-wrapper p').html('Text for icon ' + id);
  var url=$(this).find("img").attr("src");
  $(".image_col-2-wrapper img").attr('src',url);
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 50px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.text_col-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
}

.text_col-1 .clickable-li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image_col-2 {
  background-color: #5fc8c5;
  width: 650px;
}

.image_col-2-wrapper {
  padding: 40px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <!-- LEFT -->

  <div class="text_col-1">

    <!-- ICON 1 -->
    <div class="clickable-li" id="icon-1">
      <img id="image" src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/1-circle.png"><br>
      <span>Icon 1</span>
    </div>

    <!-- ICON 2 -->
    <div class="clickable-li" id="icon-2">
      <img id="image" src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/2-circle.png"><br>
      <span>Icon 2</span>
    </div>

    <!-- ICON 3 -->
    <div class="clickable-li" id="icon-3">
      <img id="image" src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/3-circle.png">
      <br>
      <span>Icon 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- RIGHT -->

  <div class="image_col-2">
    <div class="image_col-2-wrapper">
      <img src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/1-circle.png">
      <h3>Icon 1</h3>
      <p>this will be the text that appears on li click</p>
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <!---->

</div>
```

Add a click event on common class `clickable-li`.